# "You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets." Module AzureAd C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory

We use module AzureAd and sometime, we have this error : "You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.".

When we send command, we always connect. 
7 time on 10, it's working but sometime, we have "You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets."

Code here :

```
public void ChangeMailboxPassword(string "test@test.fr", string "P@55w0rd!")
{
    var secureString = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password) secureString.AppendChar(c);
    Office365PowerShellService.ExecuteAzureAdCommand("Set-AzureADUserPassword",
        new List<Parameter>
        {
            new Parameter("ObjectId", email),
            new Parameter("Password", secureString),
            new Parameter("ForceChangePasswordNextLogin", false),
        });
}

public List<PSObject> ExecuteAzureAdCommand(string name, List<Parameter> parameters)
{
    return ExecuteModuleCommand(new List<ExchangeCommand> { new ExchangeCommand(name, parameters) });
}

private List<PSObject> ExecuteModuleCommand(List<ExchangeCommand> exchangeCommands, string script = null)
{
    var initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initialSessionState.ImportPSModule(new[] { "AzureAD" });
    using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
    using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        runspace.Open();
        powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
        var secureString = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in PowerShellPassword) secureString.AppendChar(c);
        var credential = new PSCredential(PowerShellUserName, secureString);
        powerShell.AddCommand("Connect-AzureAD");
        powerShell.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
        powerShell.Invoke();
        powerShell.Commands.Clear();
        foreach (var exchangeCommand in exchangeCommands)
        {
            powerShell.AddCommand(exchangeCommand.Name);
            foreach (var parameter in exchangeCommand.Parameters)
            {
                if (parameter.Value == null)
                    powerShell.AddParameter(parameter.Name);
                else
                    powerShell.AddParameter(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);
            }

            if (exchangeCommand.Arguments.Count > 0)
            {
                powerShell.AddArgument(exchangeCommand.Arguments);
            }
        }

        if (script != null) powerShell.AddScript(script);

        var psObjects = powerShell.Invoke();

        runspace.Close();
        return psObjects?.ToList();
    }
}
```

I think, it's not working when is execute in concurrency but i don't understand why.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to wrap the Azure AD PowerShell cmdlet module here, instead of directly calling the API to set the password?

Comment: We use it for manage licence and active or not the azure ad account. Without this module, 1 year ago, we can't do that with graph api. Actually it's possible to change password and manage licence with api ?

Comment: Everything you can do with the AzureAD module you can also do with Azure AD Graph API (some cmdlets use Microsoft Graph API instead).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http 
passwordProfile need "Directory.AccessAsUser.All", it's not possible to use "Application" :(

Comment: We can use our admin account for update passwordProfil of an another user ?

Comment: Yes, you can use MS Graph to update passwordProfile of another user by hitting https://microsoft.graph/v1.0/users/{User id} and pass JSON data fields to updated but first you need to have Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission. If you use Application to do so you need to assign roles to that Application and the [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).